# customize the 2 colors in css border style

Tags: html, css, border

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg2P8/)

```
<div class="boo">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.boo{
   border-left: 12px ridge red;
}
```

and i want to customize the two colors. I tried to put this `outline-color:12px solid darkblue` in the class boo but it doesn't work..

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/mg2P8/1/ ?

Comment: no. I want to edit the 2 colors in the left side (and those only to be appeared)

Comment: is this the desired effect? http://jsfiddle.net/uyTd7/1/

Comment: @yaylitzis : here you go http://jsfiddle.net/mg2P8/3/

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan yes that's it! post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain two distinct colours for a 12px left border, just give a 6px-wide red left border  for `.boo` element and another 6px.wide blue left border for the inner paragraph

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyTd7/1/

CSS

```
.boo {
    border-left: 6px solid red;
}

p {
    border-left: 6px solid blue;
}
```

But this will work until you have two elements and no margin or padding between: if you had one single element (e.g. a  `<p>`) you could reach the same result on modern browser using `box-shadow` property (with vendor prefixes where necessary), e.g.

```
p {
    border-left: 6px solid red;
    box-shadow: -6px 0 0 blue;
}
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cq78/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can add another 'border'

**1. Using outline** (wont work with rounded corners though)
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

**2. Using :after & :before**

:after and :before lets you create a whole new element with fully customize-able border (and outline). The limit is your creativity

**3. Border style & image**

There are many kind of border style such as solid, dashed, dotted, ridge etc. Also you can just easily use repeating image for your border

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.boo{
    border-left: 12px solid red;
    outline:12px solid darkblue ;
}
p{
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

one limitation is IE6 and IE7 don't support the outline property.